# How can the function numpy.argmax() handle a list with numbers and characters

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, argmax

How can I determine the row with the highest value in index=0 even if index=1 is a character?

I have an array of lists with two positions, where the first position is a number and the second position is a character.

```
A=np.array([[150,"A"],[9,1],[9,14]])
B=np.argmax(A, axis=0)
```

I should receive this:

```
[0 2]
```

But I get this:

```
[1 0]
```

I am not sure what the output for the seconde position is but for the first position it should be 0. What did I get wrong about the function? Even slicing did not work out.

Comment: DId you look at `A` before trying to do the `argmax`?  What's the `dtype`?

Comment: Well, the type gets converted to characters, but I tried doing this: 
A=np.array([[150,"A"],[9,1],[9,14]], dtype='|i, i')
Still doesn't help.

Comment: So it's giving you the right argmax for characters.  If you want it to ignore the 'A` you have get rid of it even before make the array.  You might want to rethink the task, because mixing characters and numbers in an array can give all kinds of problems, not just this.

Comment: I was hoping to stick those value pairs together, because it is not a numerical matrix what I am handling. It's more a value pair, where I can treat the first value as number. Anyways thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. I do not know, if I will run into issues later on!

```
A=np.array([(150,"A"),(30,"B"),(9,"14")], dtype='object')
c=np.argmax(A, axis=0)
```